# ImageView is null (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set the srcCompat of an ImageView but got this error instead.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pangelyn/com.example.pangelyn.SwipeRight}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference`

I've checked multiple post in SO already but nothing seems to work.

Java file:

```
private void loadLocale() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString("Lang","");
    setLocale(language);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView_flag);

    if (language.equals("en")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.usa);
    }
    else if (language.equals("in")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.indonesia);
    }
    else if (language.equals("fil")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.philippines);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_flag"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/philippines" />
```

EDIT:

```
2020-02-13 23:32:37.312 9854-9854/com.example.pangelyn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pangelyn, PID: 9854
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pangelyn/com.example.pangelyn.SwipeRight}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.pangelyn.SwipeRight.loadLocale(SwipeRight.java:164)
    at com.example.pangelyn.SwipeRight.onCreate(SwipeRight.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Exception says it's `setBackground()` but the code you posted has `setImageResource()`. Please post your complete stacktrace. Also note that `==` does not work for string comparison, use `equals()` instead.

Comment: But, I didn't set any background

Comment: do you have `"@drawable/stroke` file?

Comment: Yes I do have that file.

Comment: Yes and that's why the stacktrace is the first step to figure out where exactly the crash is occurring in.

Comment: No it's not in stroke.

Comment: @Nodoodle You might have used wrong activity layout, check layout file used in `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setBackgroundResource()` instead of `setImageResource()`

Comment: and use  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.id)

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same error.

Comment: is your loadLocale func before setContenView?

Comment: Yes it's before it